# InDesign CS6 - Export selected pages OR Select all objects on page

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, optimization, selections

I'm looking for a way in InDesign CS6 to do one or both of the following:

1) Export one or more pages based on the selection in the Pages panel
**without** relying on the Range selector in the Export panel.

[image: quickly select and export non-adjacent pages?]

2) Select all items in the current page, **not in the current spread**, using a shortcut and whithout separating the page from the spread first.

Note: I'm exporting to PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding #1, I [posted an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20720/5489) on a similar post where I used a script to exclude "draft" pages. Perhaps you could use that, or flip the script to only include pages that you mark?

As for #2, that can be accomplished with a script. Give this a try:

```
var currentPage = app.activeWindow.activePage; // Find the active page.

ItemsOnPage = currentPage.pageItems.length; // Get the number of items on the page.

for (var i=0; i<ItemsOnPage; i++) // Loop through every item.
{
    currentPage.pageItems.everyItem().select(); // Select every item.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The object selection script works perfectly. Now I can quickly export a specific page without worrying about named ranges, sections etc. For the record, this was for website prototyping purposes.
I haven't tried the other script yet, but the concept of tagging a page to exclude/include it for export sounds very interesting.